# Obscure KeyStoreException errors when encrypting and decrypting data

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore

I have an `EncryptionManager` class that is used to encrypt and decrypt data using the Android KeyStore. The implementation works fine for 99% of users, but for some of them we are seeing occasional obscure crashes such as

```
Fatal Exception: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
   at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1693)
   at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1750)
   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
   at com.app.encryption.implementation.EncryptionManager.encryptData(EncryptionManager.kt:39)
Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Key not found
   at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1555)
   at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1750)
   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:109)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2984)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1084)
   at com.app.encryption.implementation.EncryptionManager.encryptData(EncryptionManager.kt:39)
```

and

```
Fatal Exception: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
   at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:609)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
   at com.app.encryption.implementation.EncryptionManager.decryptData(EncryptionManager.kt:68)
Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid argument
   at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:356)
   at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)
   at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.finish(KeyStoreOperation.java:127)
   at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.finish(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:228)
   at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:181)
   at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
   at com.app.encryption.implementation.EncryptionManager.decryptData(EncryptionManager.kt:68)
```

It also seems to happen only on less common devices like the Motorola Edge Plus, the Moto G Pure, the Nokia X100, and other misc devices. I haven't seen these crashes happen on a Pixel or any other widely popular device.

My `EncryptionManager` class looks like this:

```
class EncryptionManager {

  private val cipher by lazy {
      Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_PATTERN)
  }

  private val charset by lazy {
      charset(CHARSET_NAME)
  }

  private val keyStore by lazy {
      KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE).apply {
          load(null)
      }
  }

  private val keyGenerator by lazy {
      KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, KEY_STORE_TYPE)
  }

  fun encryptData(keyAlias: String, data: String): String {
      return cipher.run {
          init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, generateSecretKey(keyAlias))

          val ivString = Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT)
          var stringToEncrypt = ivString + IV_SEPARATOR
          val bytes = doFinal(data.toByteArray(charset))

          stringToEncrypt += Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
          stringToEncrypt
      }
  }

  fun decryptData(keyAlias: String, encryptedData: String): String {
      return cipher.run {
          val split = encryptedData.split(IV_SEPARATOR.toRegex())

          if (split.size != 2) {
              throw IllegalArgumentException(IV_ERROR_MESSAGE)
          }

          val ivString = split[0]
          val encryptedString = split[1]
          val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode(ivString, Base64.DEFAULT))

          init(
              Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
              getSecretKey(keyAlias),
              ivSpec,
          )

          val decryptedData = doFinal(Base64.decode(encryptedString, Base64.DEFAULT))
          String(decryptedData)
      }
  }

  fun deleteAllData() {
      val aliases = keyStore.aliases().iterator()
      aliases.forEach {
          try {
              keyStore.deleteEntry(it)
          } catch (e: Exception) {
              Timber.e(e)
          }
      }
  }

  private fun generateSecretKey(keyAlias: String): SecretKey {
      return keyGenerator.apply {
          init(
              KeyGenParameterSpec
                  .Builder(keyAlias, PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                  .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                  .setEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                  .build(),
          )
      }.generateKey()
  }

  private fun getSecretKey(keyAlias: String): SecretKey {
      return (keyStore.getEntry(keyAlias, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry).secretKey
  }

  companion object {
      private const val TRANSFORMATION_PATTERN = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
      private const val KEY_STORE_TYPE = "AndroidKeyStore"
      private const val CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8"
      private const val IV_SEPARATOR = "]"
      private const val IV_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Passed data is incorrect. There was no IV specified with it."
  }
}
```

I've spent the last week searching other KeyStore related issues, but I haven't been able to find anything that might explain why the crashes are only happening to a small subset of users. Is there something wrong with my `EncryptionManager` implementation? Something else I'm missing?

Comment: Java afaik only supports PKCS#5 padding, Android probably same but that shouldn't be the issue because it works for most. The other thing you shouldn't do is share Cipher/KeyGenerator instances across threads, they are usually not threadsafe, so in case there are threads involved it maybe fails if one thread initializes the cipher, then another one reinits the same one and the other maybe no longer finds its key. You do get strange errors that are rather rare because threads rarely happen at the same time but this can cause strange errors. If you want to reuse them, `ThreadLocal`

Comment: @zapl there definitely are threads involved, so that's a great place to start! Instead of the `cipher` being `lazy` should I just create it as a local variable first thing inside of `encryptData` and `decryptData`?

Comment: Yep, that would be the most common way of not getting into trouble. It's not really worth creating them lazily just once, the heavy operation is the encryption itself, not those few bytes of state that ciphers have. Same for the KeyGen. Things you init in threads are not safe to be init'd in mulitple threads at the same time

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try it out! Do you think it's fine to keep `charset` and `keyStore` as lazy? or would you recommend inlining all of the variable creation?

Comment: charset should be fine, that's read only. But `deleteAllData` doesn't sound very threadsafe either.

Comment: gotcha! thanks a bunch for the help, I really appreciate it! I'll report back in a few days on if it seems to be fixed